# Socket.IO not reconnecting after Node server restart on Swift app

Tags: swift, socket.io

I've recently updated a project that I was working on some time ago for the latest version of Socket.IO.  It was working fine with the earlier version but I'm now having the issue of the client not reconnecting after restarting the server.

I originally used a setup similar to this, which I'm hoping to keep:

https://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/

With the "New Configuration" code below, the app successfully connects to the server on startup but does not reconnect when the server is restarted.  When this happens, `on.disconnect` does not get called  and the `socket.status` reveals a state of `.connecting`, which is never resolved.

I actually created an entirely new project when I added the new socket files and the old project still works fine, while the new one does not.

I've added the config options that I would think should work.  Any other ideas?

**New Configuration:**

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: socketURL)!, config: [.reconnects(true), .forceNew(true)])

class SocketIOManager {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    var socket: SocketIOClient = manager.defaultSocket
    init() {

        socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
            print("connected")
        }

        socket.on("disconnect") {data, ack in
            print("disconnected")
        }
    }
}
```

**Old Configuration:**

```
class SocketIOManager {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: socketURL)!)


    init() {

        socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
            print("connected")
        }

        socket.on("disconnect") {data, ack in
            print("disconnected")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why make your classes inherit from `NSObject`? This is not Objective-C, classes don't need to have a base class, so unless you explicitly need the inherited functionality, don't inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: I'd taken that from the tutorial article I linked.  Not sure if there was functionality in the tutorial that used it, but that's the not the case with my current setup so I removed it.  I updated the question to take it out.  Thanks.